# spookyjs stops running without error

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I'm building a tool that logs into a website and visits a high number of pages that are listed in an array. Everytime I run this CasperJS seems to hang when visiting the 36th link. I tried removing the 36th link, but then it just hangs at the next one.

Could it be a memory problem? When CasperJS hangs in the debug log there is no error. When I run top on the server I'm not seeing any phantomJS processes running anymore.

```
spooky.then([{user: account.user, pass: account.pass, urls: urls}, function(){
    this.wait(2000, function() {
        this.fill(".signin-form", {
          email: user,
          password: pass
           }, true);
        var i = 0;
         var spookyObj = this
         function visitPages () {
            spookyObj.wait(5000, function(){
              spookyObj.thenOpen(urls[i], function(url){
               spookyObj.emit('visitedURL', url[i]);
               i ++
               if (i < urls.length) visitPages();
              });
            });
          }
          visitPages();
    });

}]);
```

Debug log

```
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "<URL>"                                                          
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other,    willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false                                         
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=<URL>, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
```

Comment: Do you have a top-level `spooky.then()` call after that block? Maybe the script simply finished and exited.

Comment: It doesnt seem like that as the URL array is much longer